# Is there a method to know the taskList ID from a google space?

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, google-tasks-api, google-chat

I´m working on a Google Apps Script project within the google spaces REST API, google sheets, google tasks and others. The thing is that i create a google space from a SpreadSheet in google sheets making use of the REST API methods of google's documentation but i want also to create tasks that belongs to the space created before but when i try to insert new tasks i need the space's taskList ID but i don´t know how or where to obtain it.

I tried to see what the http response brings me after i create a new space, but i don´t see nothing related to the tasks.

Comment: Did you manage to do that ? I'm also trying to automatize the creation of shared tasks within a space